# IP address remains unchanged when switching from one WiFi network to another

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dhcp, ip-address

I sometimes have to switch between two WiFi networks on my Windows 7 machine, A (192.168.1.*) and B (192.168.3.*). Both networks use DHCP and my network properties are set to use a DHCP address ("Obtain an IP address automatically").

Most of the time I'm connected to network A. When I connect to network B my IP address from network A (192.168.1.123) remains, so of course, I cannot connect to anything until I manually run `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` to get an IP on the network B subnet. This is quite annoying! How do I get this to happen automatically?

When I connect back to network A, or to any other WiFi network, my IP address is assigned from DHCP automatically, as expected.

Comment: Are you using these two wifi connections as separate networks, or to extend one network?

Comment: Do the networks have different names (SSIDs)?

Comment: @grawity Yes they have different SSIDs.

Comment: @K.Davis I'm not sure what you mean by "extend one network". They connect to different subnets on the same physical network with the same router - but my machine wouldn't know that.

Comment: Why not configure the second router as repeater and keep the original IPs across the whole network ?

Comment: @EM0 ^^^ Overmind's suggestion is where I was getting towards with my question.

Comment: The whole network set-up is not going to be changed due to one client machine experiencing a somewhat annoying issue. It obviously *should* get the IP from DHCP. I'm looking to correct that, if possible.